# Is WPF/COM Interop a longshot?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, com-interop

Per MSDN, it looks like the wall I just hit is a solid one:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly.aspx

> The GetEntryAssembly method can return null when a managed assembly has been loaded from an unmanaged application. For example, if an unmanaged application creates an instance of a COM component written in C#, a call to the GetEntryAssembly method from the C# component returns null, because the entry point for the process was unmanaged code rather than a managed assembly.

Until I decided to start using `ResourceDictionary` and `MergedDictionaries`, I had lots, lots of redundant XAML. I removed all `<controls:MyCustomControl.Resources>`, leaving only this:

```xml
<controls:GlossyContentControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack:application:,,,,/MyApp.Namespace;component/Themes/generic.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</controls:GlossyContentControl.Resources>
```

I can build the project, but when I open up the designer for a window that uses any of my *glossy content controls* I get an IOException, "**Cannot create an instance of "MyShinyNewControl". Click here to hide detail**, and then in the error list it also says *Cannot create an instance of "MyShinyNewControl"*, although the solution builds (but blows up with the same IOException when I run it through COM).

The project is a **class library** being the presentation layer of a solution that contains a bunch of class libraries, the main one exposes an object being instantiated by some VB6 code. Before I introduced the notion of shared resources/styles, it worked like a charm, but I had tons of redundant XAML everywhere.

Is there a work-around to make it work through COM, or the work-around is to duplicate all the styles everywhere?

---

Stack trace for the exception in the designer:

> Cannot locate resource 'themes/generic.xaml'.
>      at MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourcePart.GetStreamCore(FileMode mode, FileAccess access
>      at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.GetStream(FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
>      at System.IO.Packaging.PackWebResponse.CachedResponse.GetResponseStream()
>      at System.IO.Packaging.PackWebResponse.GetResponseStream()
>      at System.IO.Packaging.PackWebResponse.get_ContentType()
>      at MS.Internal.WpfWebRequestHelper.GetContentType(WebResponse response)
>      at MS.Internal.WpfWebRequestHelper.GetResponseStream(WebRequest request, ContentType& contentType)
>      at System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.set_Source(Uri value)
>      at System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfSharedBamlSchemaContext.b__1c4(Object target, Object value)
>      at System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfKnownMemberInvoker.SetValue(Object instance, Object value)
>      at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(XamlMember member, Object obj, Object value)
>      at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(Object inst, XamlMember property, Object value)

And at run-time, stack trace for the XamlParseException (exception translated from French):

> Type reference cannot find a type named '{clr-namespace:MyApp.Common.Controls}GlossyContentControl'.
>     at MS.Internal.Xaml.Context.ObjectWriterContext.ServiceProvider_Resolve(String qName)
>      at MS.Internal.Xaml.ServiceProviderContext.System.Windows.Markup.IXamlTypeResolver.Resolve(String qName)
>      at System.Xaml.Replacements.TypeTypeConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
>      at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.CreateObjectWithTypeConverter(ServiceProviderContext serviceContext, XamlValueConverter`1 ts, Object value)
>      at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.CreateFromValue(ServiceProviderContext serviceContext, XamlValueConverter`1 ts, Object value, XamlMember property)
>      at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_CreateFromValue(ObjectWriterContext ctx, XamlValueConverter`1 typeConverter, Object value, XamlMember property, String targetName, IAddLineInfo lineInfo)

What's odd is that if I open up the designer for any *glossy content control*, the styles are applied and everything looks like it should. But the window that hosts such controls can't render them.

---

Here's an overview of the solution:

- VB6 ActiveX dll instantiates managed code and runs a functionality written in C#
- C# functionality fetches data, defines view models and instantiates a WPF window
- The WPF window is displayed and everything works

There was no app.xaml involved, the code was just instantiating `Window` objects and calling `ShowDialog()` and it worked.

At one point in the introduction of shared resources, it seemed I needed an `app.xaml`, so I made one and instead of `Application Definition` I set its *build action* to `Page`. Doing this allowed usage of my `GlossyContentControl` which I used to replace some `UserControl` objects with instances of that custom content control.

Since I still don't have an *entry point* and no WPF application per se, I think WPF is having a hard time figuring out what I'm trying to do here. One thing I have not tried yet is making an actual WPF application (another assembly) with a custom entry point, so my class library can "launch" the WPF application in some sort of "idle" mode that just waits for windows to be instantiated and displayed. Would this work or be a formidable waste of time?

Comment: What's the exception stack trace?

Comment: @SLaks added stack traces for exceptions I'm getting at this point - they've changed accordingly with everything I've tried, I don't know what to tweak anymore, no matter what I do there's always an exception somewhere.

Comment: Your URI syntax is incorrect, try the 4th flavor in this section : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx#Programming_with_Pack_URIs

Comment: Wow it's even worse - now *nothing* works, and I get an error saying "Pack URI '...' is not valid in this project." - the resources are actually defined in the same assembly as where they're being used. Should I create a seperate assembly just for my resource dictionaries?